# How many links must a webpage have for it to be ok according to google?

Tags: google, content, yahoo

The home page of the help section of my site (help.clubcatcher.com) received the following report after running it through powermapper tools:

> Avoid "doorway" pages created just for search engines or other "cookie cutter" approaches such as affiliate programs with little or no original content. This page looks suspicious because it is full of text and keywords, but has very few on-site links.

Currently it has four direct links along with a text box for people to fill out of they want to search for answers.

What is the real formula powermapper uses to determine whether a page uses a cookie-cutter approach or a doorway approach? For example, how many links minimum are required per page? or what are the maximum words allowed per page?

I'll use any valuable answers offered towards new webpages I create.

Comment: I would not sweat it. It sounds like a bazillion other pages such as search pages. Take these tools with salt. Sometimes the advice applies, and sometimes it does not. Tools cannot see what we see.

Comment: BTW- I like giving you up-votes on your questions because it appears you are a savant in creating really really good and original questions. If I were a boss and seeking someone to work for me, I would be calling you immediately!

Comment: I agree with @closetnoc, I wouldn't sweat it either. The platform my team uses at work has a lot of great features but some of the information is dated or simply inaccurate, so you really have to take it with a grain of salt and use best judgment.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with previous comments but am "answering" this question so it doesn't come up as unanswered.

There is nothing about that page that makes me think it's a doorway page. If you had a separate domain, rather than a `help` subdomain, it might be more of a concern.

That said, a bit more (unique) content couldn't hurt, I doubt that page even has 250 words and it doesn't have any images larger than thumbnails.